# How to get category ID from category name in Discord.js

Tags: categories, discord.js

How would I get the category ID from the Category Name? Im using discord.js 11.6.4. Currently I have

```
let category = message.guild.channels.find(cat=> cat.name === categoryName)
```

This currently on returns the category name based on the name, which is dumb. How would I find the ID using the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `category.id` since you've defined it as a variable.

Also, that could return any type of `GuildChannel` so if you want it to strictly be a `category` check it using `if (category.type === "category")`